# Get specifics URLs from file with different ending

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, file, grep

For example I want to get all results that have this starts:

```
https://ex.some.thing/+/path/to/something/XXXXXXX/YYYYYYYY
```

where X and Y value change. They consist only of small characters and numbers.

I tried the following but no success:

```
grep -i "https://ex.some.thing/+/path/to/something/[a-z0-9]*/[a-z0-9]*"
```

Comment: what about star symbol to +

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Comment: ah, grep with -E option to use reg exp. For the special characters like +, you need an escape such as \+, \/, \: and so on.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show some example input and the expected output.

Comment: Do you want to match a literal `+`? Try `grep -i "^https://ex\.some\.thing/\+/path/to/something/[a-z0-9]*/[a-z0-9]*"`.

Comment: Still no success.

Comment: `grep '^https://ex.some.thing/+/path/to/something*'`

Comment: Doesn't work either